# Getting Selected Dropdown content to show in a form-generated email

Tags: php, forms

I have a small contact form:

```
          <form method="post" action="contact.php" name="contactform" id="contactform">

        <fieldset>

        <legend>Please fill in the following form to contact us</legend>

        <label for="name"><span class="required">*</span> Your Name</label>
        <input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="30" value="" /> 

        <br />

        <label for="company"><span class="required">*</span> Company</label>
        <input name="company" type="text" id="name" size="30" value="" /> 

        <br />

        <label for="email"><span class="required">*</span> Email</label>
        <input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="30" value="" />

        <br />
        <label for="phone"><span class="required">*</span> Phone</label>
        <input name="phone" type="text" id="phone" size="30" value="" />

        <br />
        <label for="purpose"><span class="required">*</span> Purpose</label>
        <select id="purpose" style="width: 300px; height:35px;">
             <option value="I am interested in your services">I am interested in your services!</option>
             <option value="I am interested in a partnership">I am interested in a partnership!</option>
             <option value="I am interested in a job">I am interested in a job!</option>
        </select>

        <br />
        <label for=comments><span class="required">*</span> Comments</label>
        <textarea name="comments" cols="40" rows="3"  id="comments" style="width: 350px;"></textarea>

        <p><span class="required">*</span> Please help us control spam.</p>

        <label for=verify accesskey=V>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;3 + 1 =</label>
        <input name="verify" type="text" id="verify" size="4" value="" style="width: 30px;" /><br /><br />

        <input type="submit" class="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />

        </fieldset>

        </form>
```

I want to send the results of the form in a php generated email. Everything is coming through except the selected contents of the "purpose" drop down.

Here is the PHP:

```
<?php
```

if(!$_POST) exit;

```
$name       = $_POST['name'];
$company        = $_POST['company'];
    $email      = $_POST['email'];
    $phone      = $_POST['phone'];
    $purpose    = $_POST['purpose'];
    $comments   = $_POST['comments'];
    $verify     = $_POST['verify'];

    if(trim($name) == '') {
        echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! You must enter your name.</div>';
        exit();
     } else if(trim($company) == '') {
        echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter your company name.</div>';
        exit(); 
    } else if(trim($email) == '') {
        echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter a valid email address.</div>';
        exit();
    } else if(trim($phone) == '') {
        echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter a valid phone number.</div>';
        exit();
    } else if(!isEmail($email)) {
        echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! You have enter an invalid e-mail address, try again.</div>';
        exit();
    }

    if(trim($comments) == '') {
        echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter your message.</div>';
        exit();
    } else if(trim($verify) == '') {
        echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter the verification number.</div>';
        exit();
    } else if(trim($verify) != '4') {
        echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! The verification number you entered is incorrect.</div>';
        exit();  
    }

    if($error == '') {

        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $comments = stripslashes($comments);
        }


     // Configuration option.
     // Enter the email address that you want to emails to be sent to.
     // Example $address = "joe.doe@yourdomain.com";

     $address = "myname@email.com";




     // Configuration option.
     // i.e. The standard subject will appear as, "You've been contacted by John Doe."

     // Example, $e_subject = '$name . ' has contacted you via Your Website.';

     $e_subject = 'You\'ve been contacted by ' . $name . '.';


     // Configuration option.
     // You can change this if you feel that you need to.
     // Developers, you may wish to add more fields to the form, in which case you must be sure to add them here.

     $e_body = "You have been contacted by $name.\r\n\n";
     $e_content = "Comments: \"$comments\"\r\n\n";
     $e_company = "Company: $company\r\n\n";
     $e_purpose = "Reason for contact: $purpose\r\n";

     $e_reply = "You can contact $name via email, $email or via phone $phone";

     $msg = $e_body . $e_content . $e_company . $e_purpose . $e_reply;

     if(mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, "From: $email\r\nReply-To: $email\r\nReturn-Path: $email\r\n")) {


     // Email has sent successfully, echo a success page.

     echo "<fieldset>";         
     echo "<div id='success_page'>";
     echo "<h1>Email Sent Successfully.</h1>";
     echo "<p>Thank you <strong>$name</strong>, your message has been submitted to us.</p>";
     echo "</div>";
     echo "</fieldset>";

     } else {

     echo 'ERROR!';

     }

}

function isEmail($email) { // Email address verification, do not edit.

return(preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]])\.)+(ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i",$email));

}
?>
```

What am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select needs a name='purpose'

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have set an ID for your drop-down menu, but not a name. It should look like this:

```
<select name="purpose" id="purpose" style="width: 300px; height:35px;">
         <option value="I am interested in your services">I am interested in your services!</option>
         <option value="I am interested in a partnership">I am interested in a partnership!</option>
         <option value="I am interested in a job">I am interested in a job!</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

change:

```
<select id="purpose" style="width: 300px; height:35px;">
```

to:

```
<select id="purpose" name="purpose" style="width: 300px; height:35px;">
```

Answer (score 1):

The "Purpose" dropdown element has an id but no name.  The name controls what is sent in the POST request when the form is submitted -- items with no name are not posted.